# undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason, I get the "undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class" error when I run my application.

The weird thing is that it seems to happen only on the first start after I boot my machine up and start the server. If I refresh page - it loads fine. If I restart my server - it works fine too.

I use rails 3.0.9 with ruby 1.9.2 on windows7 and I think it started happenning after I upgraded to 3.0.7. At least, with 3.0.3 I didn't get this.

Here's the trace:

```
[2011-06-28 15:16:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-06-28 15:16:39] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
[2011-06-28 15:16:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5292 port=3000
[2011-06-28 15:27:18] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:21:in `call'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-28 15:27:21 +0400
  Processing by GamesController#index as HTML
  Category Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Game Load (17.0ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."approved" = 't' AND "games"."published" = 't' ORDER BY approved_at DESC LIMIT 3

...

Rendered games/_game.haml (7.0ms)
Rendered games/index.haml within layouts/application (574.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 638ms (Views: 586.0ms | ActiveRecord: 28.0ms)
[2011-06-28 15:27:23] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: ��������� �� ����� ����-���������� ��������� ������������� �����������.
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323:in `write'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323:in `<<'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:323:in `_write_data'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:295:in `send_body_string'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:186:in `send_body'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:103:in `send_response'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:86:in `run'
    D:/dev/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 16):

I removed the following lines from development.rb

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Not sure if this is right, but it worked for me.

Comment: All I needed to do was comment out this line only: `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`

Comment: ran into this while upgrading an old rails app

Answer (score 11):

I experimented the same issue after upgrading my OS.
If setup was done using RVM, only use the following command :

```
rvm repair all
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after I added haml to my Gemfile. It appeared to be a bug in a rails update for rails 3.1

Updating rails to 3.2.2 and haml to 3.1.4 fixed the problem. More info about the bug can be [found here](https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/395).

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, and I found that the database on the server had no data in it - my restore had failed as I forgot to create a login role required by the db. As soon as I correctly restored the db from the backup, rails worked flawlessly.

I'm not sure if you're in a similar situation, but I thought I'd let you know how I solved it just in case you're in the same boat I was in :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

remove this line in  development.rb for me worked

> config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true

The message

> undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class

is not the root cause of the problem, but the last error message shown

After checking the log, I can see another error

> [2012-04-28 21:37:59] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `debug_rjs=' for ActionView::Base:Class

and according to [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d8f23ca627df85b33fe8db87db5483c10b62bfe6)

debug_rj is removed. Therefore removing it from config helped

Note:

As in [here](https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails/issues/1) it is still suggested to be added in the README...

[Another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445917/rails-3-1-0-undefined-method-page-cache-extension-for-actioncontrollerbase) regarding this same issue

Answer (score 0):

I commented both lines out in my development.rb

```
#config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true

#config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

but the problem was still there.  I had just dropped and recreated my database so I thought maybe it was the lack of data as stated above.  After creating a record, I was still without success.  Finally, I did a full restart, in my case....

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I was now able to run my rails apps now.  Although not a solid fix, it may be of some help.

Upon starting my rails app, I noticed that not all my changes for the recent pull were showing up?  I noticed that I had changed a .js file to a .js.erb file.  When I did my commit I used git add .   This left both files.  I went back and issued git add -u   I did another commit, precompiled and restart...now all my changes are there and the error is gone.  Seems that example.js in the same dir as example.js.erb were causing the issue.  Although the restart may have helped, I believe these files may have been the cause.  Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem but didn't find either of the lines

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
```

or

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

in development.rb.

Instead I comment out

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

which was near the top of my `development.rb` and it worked. I am working with an OpenShift generated Rails 4 app so that might be the reason for the absence of the above lines. Or maybe they've been deprecated since the question was initially asked / solved, so this might help someone new to the issue.