# Rails 3.1.0 - undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I try load my rails 3.1 app I just get this error. Any ideas?

`undefined method 'page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class`

Comment: just got the error myself, very strange, page refresh fixed it but I'm trying to find out what caused it. Can't seem to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somewhere I've read that it could be caused because of empty database - do You have one? Check if there You have any records ;) This resolved my problem with it.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the following lines from development.rb

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Not sure if this is right, but it worked for me.