# undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class with BRCOBRANCA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, page-caching

I'm executing Rails 3.2.1 with Ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu.
When I execute "rails s" on console this message appears: **undefined method `page_cache_extension' for ActionController::Base:Class**

I tryed comment these lines:

config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true

config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

But don't worked for me.

The project I try run is this -> https://github.com/kivanio/brcobranca_exemplo used for generate Brazilian docket on format PDF.

Someone have any idea for help me at this problem?

Grateful.

Comment: This is a potential duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505817/undefined-method-page-cache-extension-for-actioncontrollerbaseclass

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean by: "This is a potential duplicate". About this link, I tried those solutions, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 12.04, on the current master branch of your project, I was able to clone the repository, run `bundle install` and `rake db:migrate` then `rails server`, and the site came up. Are there any differences between master and what you're trying to run?

Comment: Hi friend, I probably should have set something wrong. I created a new directory and cloned the repository, ran the `bundle install`, `rake db: migrate`, `rails server` application again and it worked. Surely I must have forgotten something. Thank you.